# Jython - Class Cast Exception with PyObject

Tags: java, python, jython

I am trying to create and cast an object in Jython and I am receiving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "MainThread" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.python.core.PySingleton cannot be cast to resources.ixia.IxNetType
at resources.ixia.IxNetFactory.create(IxNetFactory.java:34)
at resources.ixia.IxiaTest.run(IxiaTest.java:34)
at resources.ixia.IxiaTest.<init>(IxiaTest.java:14)
at resources.ixia.IxiaTest.main(IxiaTest.java:42)
```

Here is the code:

```
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class IxNetFactory {

    private PyObject ixNetClass;
    private PythonInterpreter interpreter;

    public IxNetFactory(String script_dir) {
        script_dir=script_dir.replace("\\", "/");

        interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

        interpreter.exec("import sys");             
        interpreter.exec("sys.path.append('"+script_dir+"')");
        interpreter.exec("import time");
        interpreter.exec("import os");
        interpreter.exec("from ixnetworks import IxNet");
        //interpreter.exec("from utils import sm");
        //interpreter.exec("from utils import cpf");

        ixNetClass = interpreter.get("IxNet");
    }

    /*
     * Create an IxNet object
     * 
     * Usage: ixNet.create();
     */
    public IxNetType create() {
        PyObject ixNetObject = ixNetClass.__call__();
        return (IxNetType)ixNetObject.__tojava__(IxNetType.class);
    }

    public void close() {
        interpreter.close();
    }
}
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. From all of the things I have read, I seem to be doing this correctly but I cannot get it to work.

If anyone with experience with Jython could tell me what I am doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder what `IxNet` and `IxNetType` look like.  If the source to these types is closed, can your rewrite them in such a way that minimizes their exposure but still reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but for other people who might be facing the same issue: I just had what I believe to be the same error, and fixed it. I'm guessing that the declaration of your Python class doesn't inherit from your interface.

For example, ixnet.py:

```
import IxNetType

class IxNet(IxNetType):
...
```

This is what you should have. Instead, you probably just declared IxNet as:

```
class IxNet:
...
```

which will produce the error: "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.python.core.PySingleton cannot be cast to resources.ixia.IxNetType"